# Вместо страницы записей загружается главная Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Народ, нужна ваша помощь, сам уже замучался. Делаю сайт на wordpress, есть главная страница и есть страница записей. Соответственно, хочу чтобы на странице записей выводились записи, но никак не могу этого сделать.

Что имеется. Я создал **page.php** (пробовал тут по разному, и page-blog.php и page-news.php) в него поместил вот такой код с комментарием **Template name: News**.

```
<?php /* Template name: News */ get_header(); ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()):
                    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>


                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="list-item--link"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                    <div><?php the_date() ?></div>
                    <div><?php the_content() ?></div>
                </div>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                новостей нету
            <?php endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Затем создал страницу с именем **Блог** и ярлыком **blog** и задал ей шаблон который я создал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в настройках выбрал статическую страницу для записей блога:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохранил всё это и все равно, когда захожу по ссылке localhost/site/**blog** то вижу главную страницу, вместо страницы записей. Почему? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: у меня была такая проблема после редактирования Настройки -> Чтение (на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384470/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) Как вы ее решили?

Answer (score 0):

> когда захожу по ссылке localhost/site/blog то вижу главную страницу,
>   вместо страницы записей. Почему? Что я делаю не так?

В шаблоне нет [цикла](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

Страница записей выводится шаблоном `home.php`, вам нужно просто код из вашего `page.php` перенести в этот файл и всё должно заработать.

В отсутствие файла `home.php` начинает работать `index.php`, если код главной страницы находится в этом файле, то это может объяснять то, что вместо страницы записей у вас выводится содержимое, которое вы ожидаете видеть только на главной странице