# Отображение страницы как записи. Записи для шаблона страницы

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, запись

Действую согласно [Вывод постов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIDId7lej80&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=5)

Есть  шаблон страницы Myblog и страница этого шаблона http://wordpresstestsite.ru/blog/

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Myblog
*/
?>

<?php get_header('third'); ?>


   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row">

         <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

            <?php if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
            
            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><? the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator='/', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->
            
            <?php }
            }
            ?>

            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="single.html" title="">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean sollicitudin auctor.</a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24">Jan 14, 2013</time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="single.html" title=""><img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-02.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image"></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->

            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="single.html" title="">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean sollicitudin auctor.</a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24">Jan 14, 2014</time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="single.html" title=""><img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-03.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image"></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <nav class="col full pagination">
                  <ul>
                  <li><span class="page-numbers prev inactive">Prev</span></li>
                      <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">6</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">7</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">8</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">9</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers next">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>

         </div> <!-- Primary End-->

         <div id="secondary" class="four columns end">

            <!--
            <aside id="sidebar">

               <div class="widget widget_search">
                  <h5>Search</h5>
                  <form action="#">

                     <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search here...'; }" value="Search here...">
                     <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">

                  </form>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_text">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Text Widget</h5>
                  <div class="textwidget">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                  Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                  nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus
                  a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="widget widget_categories">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                  <ul class="link-list cf">
                     <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_tag_cloud">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                  <div class="tagcloud cf">
                     <a href="#">drupal</a>
                     <a href="#">joomla</a>
                     <a href="#">ghost</a>
                     <a href="#">wordpress</a>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_photostream">
                  <h5>Photostream</h5>
                  <ul class="photostream cf">
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            </aside>
            -->
            
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

         </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

      </div>

   </div> <!-- Content End-->

   <!-- Tweets Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="tweets">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
         </div>

         <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            <!--
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            -->
         </ul>

         <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

      </div>

   </section> <!-- Tweets Section End-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Есть посты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате при открытии страницы `http://wordpresstestsite.ru/blog/` в if (have_posts()) {while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ...} отображается страница blog.php (точнее ее имя и дата публикации), а не запись `Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean sollicitudin auctor.`.

```html
   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row">

         <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

            <?php if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
            
            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><? the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator='/', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->
            
            <?php }
            }
            ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```html
                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><? the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator='/', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>
```

выводит заголовок страницы (а не название записи) и дату ее создания.

А должно быть как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое впечатление, что команда, возвращающая посты, возвращает страницу Blog (точнее ее заголовок и дату публикации) шаблона Myblog вместо вывода постов. Именно так и есть.

Подскажите как добиться отображения записей. Пытался сделать blog.php статической страницей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате стало всегда выводить начальную страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Та страница для которой Вы испоьзуете шаблон blog.php назначена в настройках страницей для вывода записей?

Comment: см. раздел 'Код не запускается / Выводится код как он есть в PHP'. Может поможет

Comment: Вы, скажем так, используете дефолтный цикл WordPress, если Вы не назначили эту страницу как стандартную для вывода записей, то в стандартном цикле будет выводиться ее контент. Можете или назначить ее в настройках или использовать WP_Query/get_posts(). Потому что на данный момент это обычная страница.

Comment: @Simon а где в админке страница задается как страница для вывода записей?

Comment: @Simon до текущего момента я думал, что записи можно отображать на любой странице. Если это не так, то подскажите как настроить страницу для этого (укажите путь из пунктов меню для настройки страницы как страницы, содержащую записи). Вы поняли структуру шаблона страницы и зависимость страницы blog.php относительно шаблона страницы?

Comment: >а где в админке страница задается как страница для вывода записей? -  Тут `/wp-admin/options-reading.php`

Comment: @Simon не помогло.

Comment: Так, я Вас немного запутал наверное, так работать не будет, т.к. будет использован другой шаблон. Отмените настройку которую Вы применили и замените стандатный цикл на WP_Query.

Comment: @Simon см. продолжение на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384561/wp-query-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b.