# WP_Query возвращает ноль записей. Записи для шаблона страницы

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, база-данных

См. [Вывод записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384470/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8). Имею следующий файл `http://wordpresstestsite.ru/blog/`

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Myblog
*/
?>

<?php get_header('third'); ?>


   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row">

         <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

            <?php /*if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); */ $query = new WP_Query();
            print_r($query);
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                ?>
            
            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_title() ?></a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <?php the_category($separator='/', '') ?>
                     <!--
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     -->
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title=""><?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumb') ?><!--<img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-01.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image">--></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->
            
            <?php } ?>

            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="single.html" title="">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean sollicitudin auctor.</a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24">Jan 14, 2013</time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="single.html" title=""><img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-02.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image"></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->

            <article class="post">

               <div class="entry-header cf">

                  <h1><a href="single.html" title="">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet Aenean sollicitudin auctor.</a></h1>

                  <p class="post-meta">

                     <time class="date" datetime="2014-01-14T11:24">Jan 14, 2014</time>
                     /
                     <span class="categories">
                     <a href="#">Design</a> /
                     <a href="#">User Inferface</a> /
                     <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                     </span>

                  </p>

               </div>

               <div class="post-thumb">
                  <a href="single.html" title=""><img src="images/post-image/post-image-1300x500-03.jpg" alt="post-image" title="post-image"></a>
               </div>

               <div class="post-content">

                  <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                  ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. </p>

               </div>

            </article> <!-- post end -->

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <nav class="col full pagination">
                  <ul>
                  <li><span class="page-numbers prev inactive">Prev</span></li>
                      <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">6</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">7</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">8</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers">9</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="page-numbers next">Next</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>

         </div> <!-- Primary End-->

         <div id="secondary" class="four columns end">

            <!--
            <aside id="sidebar">

               <div class="widget widget_search">
                  <h5>Search</h5>
                  <form action="#">

                     <input class="text-search" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search here...'; }" value="Search here...">
                     <input type="submit" class="submit-search" value="">

                  </form>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_text">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Text Widget</h5>
                  <div class="textwidget">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                  Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                  nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus
                  a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="widget widget_categories">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Categories</h5>
                  <ul class="link-list cf">
                     <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Other Stuff</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_tag_cloud">
                  <h5 class="widget-title">Tags</h5>
                  <div class="tagcloud cf">
                     <a href="#">drupal</a>
                     <a href="#">joomla</a>
                     <a href="#">ghost</a>
                     <a href="#">wordpress</a>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="widget widget_photostream">
                  <h5>Photostream</h5>
                  <ul class="photostream cf">
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="thumbnail"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

            </aside>
            -->
            
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

         </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

      </div>

   </div> <!-- Content End-->

   <!-- Tweets Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="tweets">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
         </div>

         <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            <!--
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            -->
         </ul>

         <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

      </div>

   </section> <!-- Tweets Section End-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

В результате выводит следующую страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заданные посты см. на [Вывод записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384470/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8). Подскажите как отобразить записи. Как отобразить записи для шаблона страницы? Привожу таблицу wp_posts

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло `new WP_Query(['post_type'=>'post'])` вместо `new WP_Query()`.